# Printing from an ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm taking in a text file and storing each word in an arraylist. However the problem is, when I iterate through the arraylist and print the contents, the words appear many times and not necessarily in the right order.  Here's a snippet of the code below:

```
 public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            ArrayList storeWord = new ArrayList();


            Scanner scannerWord = new Scanner(new File("word"));

            while(scannerWord.hasNext()) {
                String word = scannerWord.next();{
                    storeWord.add(word);

                    Iterator itr = storeWord.iterator();
                    while(itr.hasNext())
                        System.out.println(itr.next());

                }
```

Does anyone know what the  problem could be and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 
    ArrayList storeWord = new ArrayList();
    Scanner scannerWord = new Scanner(new File("word"));

    while(scannerWord.hasNext()) {
        storeWord.add(scannerWord.next());
    }

    Iterator itr = storeWord.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
       System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
}
```

Your 'print' loop was nested in your 'read' loop.

Answer (score 3):

You're printing out your entire list on every read. That could be why each word is displayed multiple times.

You might want:

```
Scanner scannerWord = new Scanner(new File("word"));

while(scannerWord.hasNext()) {
  String word = scannerWord.next();{
  storeWord.add(word);
}
Iterator itr = storeWord.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
  System.out.println(itr.next());
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to take your iterator and printing while loop out of the original while loop